# periodically updating a value in flask with Backgroundscheduler

Tags: python, windows, flask, apscheduler

I am working in flask through windows, and I am also using BackgroundScheduler. What I intend to do is to start the backgroundscheduler by clicking a button, afterwards, I would like to see a value increasing according to the time interval that I am specifying. The problem that I am currently having is that I need to press the start button multiple times to see the updated value.

I have the following code:

My simplified flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
# Starting my value in 0
some_value = 0

# This function only increases the variable by 1
def interval_task():
    global some_value
    some_value += 1
    
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

# A simplified route with two buttons
@app.route('/page1', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def click_buttons():
    
    img_pause = '/static/img/bootstrap_icons/pause-circle.svg'
    img_working = '/static/img/animated_captura.gif'
    sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon = True)
    sched.add_job(func = interval_task, trigger = 'interval', id = 'fetch_data_cont', seconds = 5)
    
    if request.form.get('startbtn') == 'startbtn':
    
        sched.start()
        
        # This is were I have problems. If I return the render_template, flask updates the form, but only
        # briefly, I need to keep on pressing the start button to see the updated value.

        return render_template('page1.html', img_source = img_working, some_value = some_value)
        
    if request.form.get('stopbtn') == 'stopbtn':
        
        sched.pause_job('fetch_data_cont')
        return render_template('page1.html', img_source = img_pause)  
    
    else:
        
        sched.pause_job('fetch_data_cont')
        return render_template('page1.html', img_source = img_pause)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
    #app.run(debug = True)
    app.run()
```

and in my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block leftsidebar %}
        
    <form  method="POST">
        <div class="bs-component">
            <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
                <div class="card-header">some fancy title here</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="startbtn" value="startbtn">
                    <img src="{{ img_source }}" style="width:80px;height:40px;" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
                    <hr>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="stopbtn" value="stopbtn">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        
        <div class="bs-component">
            <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
                <div class="card-header">Output</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                    <p class="card-text">
                        rms: {{ some_value }}
                    </p>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        
        
    </form>

{% endblock %}


{% block center %}

    <h2>some other fancy title for the page1</h2>
    <p><i>Some nice info.</i></p>
    <div class="bs-component">
        <div style = "background-image: href="{{ url_for('static', filename='equipo_1.png') }}";"></div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I understand that flask works this way; you press a button, it renders something new in the html, but how do I get the multiple changing output by pressing my button only once?

Perhaps my problem has an easy solution, but so far (still kind of a newb to Flask) I haven't found it. Any assistance will be appreciated.

---

**Edit:** with the suggestion of @sur.la.route I did some changes:

```
{% block leftsidebar %}
    <form  method="POST">       
       <div class="bs-component">           
          <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
              <div class="card-header">Captura continua</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <input type="submit" id="btncapt" class="btn btn-primary" name="comenzar" value="comenzar">
                      <img src="{{ img_source }}" style="width:80px;height:40px;" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
                      <hr>
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="detener" value="detener">
              </div>            
           </div>           
        </div>
     </form>        

         <div class="bs-component">         
             <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">           <div class="card-header">Respuesta</div>           <div class="card-body">
                
                <p class="card-text" id="updtval">
                    
                </p>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>  
<script>    
document.getElementById("btncapt").onclick = myTimer;       
function myTimer(some_value){   
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();         
    req.open("GET", "/intervaltask", true);          
    document.getElementById("updtval").innerHTML = "rms = " + req.responseText;         
    req.send();     
}   
setInterval(myTimer, 5000);     
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

while the changes in my flask app were minor:

```
some_value = 0

@app.route('/intervaltask')
def interval_task():
    global some_value
    some_value += 1
    # This is just to check the value on the console, it is increasing
    print (some_value)
    return str(some_value)
```

So, I can see the value increasing and the text of rms= does appear, but nothing else. I did a little [video](https://youtu.be/CZUqKRVIENQ) of the issue...

Comment: I'd use the button to start the task, then use javascript to perform an ajax request to get the updated value periodically.

Comment: @sur.la.route, thanks for your input. Could you be so kind on providing an example or a link? Kind of new to all these stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I'd recommend. I would use the button to turn it on, and then use a javascript ajax request to query the updated value periodically.

I'm sure there are some typo's but you will get the idea :)

Add a flask route that will return the value only -

```py
@app.route('/ajax')
def ajax():
    return some_value
```

Then, add a javascript function at the end of your `page1.html`, I guess in side your `block center`.

```js
<script>
(function(){

  function get_value(){
    // create an ajax request
    var q = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
    q.open("get", "/ajax", true);
    q.send();
  
    q.onload = function () {
      // update page with new value
      document.queryselector('div.bs-component p.card-text').innerHTML = "rms: " + q.responseText;

      // timeout to run again after 2 seconds
      setTimeout(get_value, 2000);
    }
  }
  
  // call the function to get it started
  get_value();

})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks sur.la.route, for your answer... I have little knowledge of JS. I was checking out many different sites, and could come with a solution that takes many parts of your idea, the problem right now is that the form is not updating the value, although it is displaying on the windows console. I think my problem resides in `document.getElementById("updtval").innerHTML = "rms = " + q.responseText;` I changed many parts of my script ("rms = " is showing), but not the value that keeps increasing (returning the value as a string)

Answer (score 0):

So... two things to tackle: the javascript is resetting itself just because of the `type="submit"` instruction, according to this other question, and its respective answer, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838529/simple-counting-javascript-task-not-working-in-flask/68838950?noredirect=1#comment121661129_68838950)

If I get rid of it, the program works well, the other thing was the order of the AJAX request. There are many sites where `send()` it's at the beginning of your starting code, but it shouldn't be there. Place it at the end. I also added some other stuff such as the type of return that you are expecting, and also in flask, I'm returning a string.

so... in the html file, the script that worked for me is:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("btncapt").addEventListener("click", startTimer);

    function startTimer(){
        var setime = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
    }

    function myTimer(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("updtval").innerHTML = "rms = " + req.responseText;
        }
        req.open("GET", "/intervaltask", true);
        req.responseType = "text";
        req.send();
    }
</script>
```

and the piece of code in your flask app can be:

some_value = 0

```
@app.route('/intervaltask') def interval_task():
    global some_value
    some_value += 1
    print (some_value)
    return str(some_value)
```

Posting this here to help newbies like myself.