# Simple counting javascript task not working in flask

Tags: javascript, flask

I am creating a Flask app, and I'm just starting trying to mix flask and javascript, my script is suuuuper easy:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="mybtn">click me to start</button>
<p>click the button to start the count</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", startTimer);
var t = 0;

function startTimer(){
  var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
}


function myTimer() {
  t = t + 1;  
  //var d = new Date();
  //var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I try to implement this into flask, it fails to start the counting... Why? What am I  doing wrong?
The Flask output doesn't show a thing, no errors, not even a glimpse of what could I be doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block leftsidebar %}
    
<form  method="POST">
    <div class="bs-component">
        <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
            <div class="card-header">start the thing</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <input type="submit" id="btncapt" class="btn btn-primary" name="start" value="start">
                <img src="{{ img_source }}" style="width:80px;height:40px;" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

</form>

<div class="bs-component">
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Respuesta</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            
            <p class="card-text" id="updtval">
                
            </p>
                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

document.getElementById("btncapt").addEventListener("click", startTimer);
var t = 0; 

function startTimer(){
    var setime = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
}

function myTimer(){
    t = t + 1;
    document.getElementById("updtval").innerHTML = t;
}

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my flask app:

```
@app.route('/vistgen', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def vgen():

img_pause = '/static/img/bootstrap_icons/pause-circle.svg'
img_working = '/static/img/animated_captura.gif'

if request.form.get('start') == 'start':

    return render_template('vistgen.html', img_source = img_working) 

else:
    
    return render_template('vistgen.html', img_source = img_pause)
```

Comment: "The Flask output doesn't show a thing" why would you expect it to? Flask is the *server*, the timer runs on the *client*. Now if the page fails to load, *then* I would be checking the flask terminal output. You however need to check the JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: @Jared Smith. I was talking about errors or exceptions... thanks for the input, though, Wasn't aware of a js terminal output (kind of new to all of this)

Comment: Not sure if this would help: https://medium.com/@crawftv/javascript-jinja-flask-b0ebfdb406b3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not because of "merging" flask with js, but how the form tag in HTML works.

When a form is submitted in HTML, with `<input type="submit">`, the action page of the form is loaded. Since it's the same page here, the page will be reloaded on submit, which means all javascript in the browser is reset (in a way).

I am assuming you are trying to submit the form without reloading the page, it is possible with async requests and you can do it by adding the following js. But note that the page won't be reloaded, so any HTML that you might be  generating on the server(flask side) will not be updated (but form will be submitted in the background).

```js
document.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  // Store reference to form to make later code easier to read
  const form = e.target;

  // Post data using the Fetch API
  fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: new FormData(form),
  });

  // Prevent the default form submit
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can see more info regarding this and how to extend here: https://pqina.nl/blog/async-form-posts-with-a-couple-lines-of-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: thanks, @Palash Bansal, for your input, I will check your link out, and see if I can come with a solution.

Comment: I didn't really get your code, or how to implement it. As you were saying, the `input type="submit"` was the problem. If I substitute that for a simple button with its id, the java script works without any further complication. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, that would make the javascript work, but if you are expecting some data in your backend when the form gets submitted, that won't happen.